# Dynamic Parameter String cannot be read by SQL attribute parameter of SQL Input Binding for Stored Procedure - Azure Function App C#

Tags: c#, azure-functions

I am trying to create an HTTP Trigger azure function that can handle dynamic parameter string for a stored procedure. I want to gather first all query parameters and pass it to the SQLAttribute parameter: @parametersString. but my variable parametersString can't be read and accessed by the SQL binding `Error: The name 'parametersString' does not exist in the current context`.

```
namespace get.workers.from.db
{
    
    public static class getWorkersSP
    {

        [FunctionName("getWorkersbySP")]
        public static IActionResult Run(
            
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", Route = null)] string parametersString, HttpRequest req,
            [Sql(commandText: "sp_GetWorkers", commandType: System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure, parameters: @parametersString,
            connectionStringSetting:"workday-t10us-SqlConnectionString")] IEnumerable<Object> result,
            ILogger log)
        {

            log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger with SQL Input Binding function processed a request.");
            // Parse query parameters
            var query = req.Query;
            
            // Create a list of parameters for the stored procedure
            var parameters = new List<SqlParameter>();

            // Loop through the query parameters and add them to the list
            foreach (var key in query.Keys)
            {
                // Get the value of the query parameter
                var value = query[key];

                // Create a new SqlParameter object with the key and value
                var parameter = new SqlParameter(key, value);

                // Add the parameter to the list
                parameters.Add(parameter);
            }

            // Transform the list of parameters to a string
            parametersString = string.Join(", ", parameters.Select(p => $"@{p.ParameterName} = {p.Value}"));

            return new OkObjectResult(result);
        }
    }
```

}

Thanks!

I have 35 stored procedure parameters that will not be always supplied so that I came up with this solution because I keep on encountering: `'Error while accessing 'param': property doesn't exist'` whenever a parameter is not included on the request.